# Set x-frame-options to allow and disallow certain URLs to frame a page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, clickjacking

I want to prevent my website from being clickjacked by someone else. So in my .htaccess file, I placed this code (which is working correctly):

```
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

My website is now secured from being iframed by any sites in the internet. However, I recently developed a mobile application that fetches pages under the about-us hosted in my website (my website contains www.mywebsite/about-us/author, www.mywebsite/about-us/company) to display the same details on the app. So what I did was I added the lines on my .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI ^about-us/$ aboutus_page
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN env=!aboutus_page
```

I want the rest of my pages to be free from being iframed except all pages under mywebsite/about-us/ "any page"

Comment: Remove `$` from `SetEnvIf` pattern.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I have removed it, but the pages under http://mysite/mobile-app/* is still being prevented from being iframed

Comment: You are defining the variable to be `aboutus_page`, whereas checking for `mobileapp_page`

Comment: Try to be less specific and see if it fixes things: `SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI about-us aboutus_page`. Not sure `env=!` is valid too, the usual syntax is `env!=`

Comment: when i perform env!= it causes me internal server error. I have done what you have suggested. but still it blocks me from iframing pages under about-us/. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At least in Apache 2.4 %{REQUEST_URI} won't work for the usual SPA kind of URI. Use %{THE_REQUEST} instead. Then SetEnvIf is not as flexible so I recommend to use simply the // sections. Just tested the below and works:

```
<If "! %{THE_REQUEST} =~ /.*about-us.*/">
  Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</If>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a second htaccess file in folder "aboutus" where you allow xframe.
so it will override the outer htaccess file.
if you just want to allow xframes in company and auther you can put htaccess files there too.